# Selenium sendKeys to the wrong input

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm facing a strange issue with the sendKeys method on my Selenium test.
In my webapp I have a lot of inputs with default values, I get those inputs with a findElements() and then I try to fill them, very simple.
To simplify, I have something like that:

```
List<WebElement> allInputs = driver().findElements(By.className("pouet"));
for (WebElement e : allInputs) {
    e.clear();
    e.sendKeys("pouet");
}
```

And it can fail because sometimes the sendKeys() fills the wrong input whereas the clear() has been correctly executed on the right input.

Does anyone has already faced this kind of issue?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

It is strange but it happened in my case, sometimes my firefoxdriver wrote in wrong field even if all fields were unique and successfully found. Small time span between two sendKeys() calls solved the issue. I wasn't using sleeps (you could try with `Thread.sleep(5000)` just for test to ensure this is it), simple verification if correct text was written in the field between these 2 calls was enough time so that next sendKeys() writes in correct field.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using those sleep in my test and maybe the text verification can be enought to avoid that, I will try it, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this, for my case sometimes my clear seemed to be failed and my sendKeys append the previous value. So I need to put Thread.sleep(1000) between e.clear() and e.sendKeys().

However based on your description it seems your issue is more to not able to point to the correct textfield. You should try to put the sleep after the sendKeys() like @acikojevic said.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using those sleep but it seems that I will be forced to :( I will try to use @acikojevic trick making a simple text verification after each sendKeys. Thanks :)

Comment: yeah as far as I know there is no way to around it. unless maybe the future driver has this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try *click*ing the input field first before clearing it. Without a click sometimes the field is not ready for clearing/input. So:

```
    e.click();
    e.clear();
    e.sendKeys("pouet");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a case where this exact thing happened. And adding the `element.click()` call didn't help!

It turned out the culprit is not selenium. There was a script on the page that ised `HTMLElement.focus()` to focus a particular element in the form depending on a condition.

So Selenium was actually racing with the JavaScript on the page for focus, and that caused this issue.